# Fetching data from API using Javascript and then pushing the value to a DIV

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to get data from a free APi : [API URL](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/posts)

I then want to push the full response into a div on my page.
I can consolelog it fine, my solution is not working.
This is what i have tried.

```
async function fetchData() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
    i = json;
    console.log(i);
    document.getElementById('matcher').innerHTML = i.toString();
}
```

Comment: What is the output of 'i'? Do you have an element in your html with id="matcher". Can you include the full html page  or an online example via jsfiddle or codesandbox or alternative?

Comment: Yes, "matcher" is the div. So the div looks like this : <div id="matcher"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function fetchData() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments').then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    // This is the JSON from our response
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('matcher').innerHTML = data[0].body;
}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
}
```

OR you can use JSON.stringify

```
async function fetchData() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments').then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    // This is the JSON from our response
    console.log(data);
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.getElementById('matcher').innerHTML = data;
}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is an array, try to render it using **map**.
Try:

```
json?.map((item, index) => document.getElementById('matcher').innerHTML = item?.title;
```

or, if you want an output in your procedure for a while, then

```
document.getElementById('matcher').innerHTML = json[0].body;
```

Moreover, you can use **innerText** instead of innerHTML render a value of some property.